# How do I send e-mail from an additional account in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010 (RTM) and I have a domain account (ac1). I have added access to another account (ac2) to Outlook. I can read e-mail from both accounts and when I hit "New e-mail" I can send an e-mail from ac1. If I reply to an e-mail sent to ac2 Outlook displays a "From" field, similar to the "To" field, pre-populated the the ac2 identity. That's all fine and dandy! *But* if I want to create a new e-mail and send it as ac2, how do I do that? I've been looking for a "New e-mail as..." button and a way of displaying the "From field" in create new message, but no luck so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dropdown box where it says from. You can choose the two accounts, or type in your "other email address" as per old versions of outlook.

Comment: But the "From" field does not show up...

Comment: Open the "options" tab within a new email, then click "From"

http://www.submitlist.com/9cf5mkv

The from field should then show up for you.